# Rails 5.1: How to override confirmation dialog with bootstrap using rails-ujs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5.1, rails-ujs

Prior to Rails 5.1 I was able to use the following to customize the confirmation dialog using bootstrap styling:

```
$ ->
  $.rails.allowAction = (link) ->
    return true unless link.attr('data-confirm')
    $.rails.showConfirmDialog(link) 
    false 

  $.rails.confirmed = (link) ->
    link.removeAttr('data-confirm')
    link.trigger('click.rails')

  $.rails.showConfirmDialog = (link) ->
    message = link.attr 'data-confirm'
    html = """
           <div class="modal" id='confirmationDialog'>
             <div class="modal-dialog">
               <div class='modal-content'>
                 <div class='modal-header'>
                   <a class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>×</a>
                   <h3>#{message}</h3>
                 </div>
                 <div class='modal-body'>
                   <p>#{link.data('body')}</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class='modal-footer'>
                   <a data-dismiss='modal' class='btn btn-default'>#{link.data('cancel')}</a>
                   <a data-dismiss='modal' class='btn btn-danger confirm'>#{link.data('ok')}</a>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           """
    $(html).modal()
    $('#confirmationDialog .confirm').on 'click', -> $.rails.confirmed(link)
```

The code stopped working with the change to rails_ujs? I've seen some articles on customizing it for SweetAlert2 but not bootstrap or other custom options.

Thanks.

Comment: jquery is no longer bundled with rails, have you tried included jquery-ujs into Gemfile?

Comment: I've heard, but haven't tried it, but if have rails_ujs abd jqueryUjs, events will be processed twice

Comment: found a gem that will do this, gem 'data-confirm-modal'

Answer (score 3):

For Rails 6, here's an example using bootstrap 4 dialogs:

Add modal dialog HTML to your base layout:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmation-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <span id="modal-content"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id='ok-button'><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add javascript to override Rails.confirm and add to your global webpack:

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs";

// Overrides default rails confirmation with bootstrap 4 confirm dialog
Rails.confirm = function(message, element) {
  let $element = $(element)
  let $dialog = $('#confirmation-modal')
  let $content = $dialog.find('#modal-content')
  let $ok = $dialog.find('#ok-button')
  $content.text(message)
  $ok.click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      $dialog.modal("hide")
      let old = Rails.confirm
      Rails.confirm = function() { return true }
      $element.get(0).click()
      Rails.confirm = old
    })
  $dialog.modal("show")
  return false;
}
```

'#modal-content' span is replaced with message text when the link/button requiring confirmation is clicked, and then the dialog is shown.

$element is the original element which gets 'clicked' if the user clicks the OK button within the dialog. This means that however complicated your rails link/button is (using posts/gets/params, etc), this simply lets that work by physically clicking it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in Rails 6 the confirm method of Rails UJS has been made public so that you can override it, as explained in this PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32404

Answer (score 0):

Got following working in Rails 5.2. First using console verify presence of 'Rails' and 'BootstrapDialog' object, then put the following in a file similar to ~/app/javascripts/prj.js:

```
"use strict"
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  var handleConfirm = function(element) {
    if (!allowAction(this)) {
      Rails.stopEverything(element)
    }
  }

  var allowAction = function(element) {
    if (element.getAttribute('data-confirm') === null) {
      return true
    }

    showConfirmDialog(element);
    return false
  }

  var confirmed = function(element, result) {
    if (result.value) {
      // User clicked confirm button
      element.removeAttribute('data-confirm')
      element.click()
    }
  }

  var showConfirmDialog = function(link) {
    BootstrapDialog.show({
    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    closable: false,
    message: $(link).attr('data-confirm'),
    buttons: [
      { 
        label: 'Cancel',
        action: function(dialogRef){
          dialogRef.close();
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'Yes',
        cssClass: 'btn-danger',
        action: function(dialogRef) {
          confirmed(link);
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  $("a[data-confirm]").on('click',handleConfirm);
});
```

Comment: wasn't able to get this to work, but likely my js skills at fault

Comment: @Steve Were you able to verify existence of Rails and BootstrapDialog objects in console? If yes, were you able to call BootstrapDialog.show() method from the console also to get the dialog to show up?

Answer (score 0):

Following [Brett Green](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523794/brett-green)'s answer, I tweaked it using Sweet Alert:

`custom_confirm_dialog.js`

```js
import Rails from '@rails/ujs';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

Rails.confirm = (message, element) => {
  console.log('message:', message)
  Swal.fire({
    titleText: '...',
    text: '...,
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonText: '...',
    confirmButtonText: '...',
    icon: 'warning'
  }).then(result => {
    if(result.isConfirmed) {
      const old = Rails.confirm;
      Rails.confirm = () => true;
      element.click();
      Rails.confirm = old;
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

  return false;
}
```

`application.js`

```
...
import Rails from '@rails/ujs';
Rails.start();
...
import '../src/javascripts/custom_confirm_dialog';
```

Working fine :)